# How to detect HTTP user agent of GET request on Amazon API Gateway?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I create an HTTP GET request method on Amazon API Gateway. Now I want to detect the client IP address and HTTP_USER_AGENT from the HTTP GET request and pass them to my custom project in headers.

Below is my mapping template that I define on aws api gateway for http GET request

[image]

And below is my http request URL

```
https://Yxz5Vp6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/alpha/post/share?auth=25142452&id=23365242
```

And reques response that I received in headers

```
    array (
  'x-amzn-apigateway-api-id' => 
  array (
    0 => 'yv9frefnud',
  ),
  'x-amzn-trace-id' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Root=1-5c247572-db8d0dc0c5aaa725bf7ad089',
  ),
  'user-agent' => 
  array (
    0 => 'AmazonAPIGateway_yv9frefnud',
  ),
  'content-type' => 
  array (
    0 => 'application/json',
  ),
  'accept' => 
  array (
    0 => 'application/json',
  ),
  'host' => 
  array (
    0 => 'fayvo-post.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com',
  ),
  'connection' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Keep-Alive',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an API Gateway [mapping template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html). Define a map that looks something like this:

```
{
  "caller_ip" : "$input.params('X-Forwarded-For')", 
  "useragent" : "$context.identity.userAgent"
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with more detail I have implemented your answer but not expected result found. Kindly once review my question again and give your answer that I have implemented right mapping or not?